# How do you call vsnprintf() safely?

Tags: c, printf, glibc

I'm porting some very old (> 10y) C code to modern Linuxes. I'm getting segmentation faults within a custom-written vsnprintf() wrapper (apparently its task is to detect duplicate output strings and intern them):

```
char* strVPrintf(const String fmt, va_list ap)
{
  /* Guess we need no more than 50 bytes. */
  int n, size = 50;
  char* p = (char*)memMalloc(size), q;

  while (1) {
    /* Try to print in the allocated space. */
    n = vsnprintf(p, size, fmt, ap);
    /* If that worked, return the string. */
    if (n > -1 && n < size) {
      break;
    }
    /* Else try again with more space. */
    if (n > -1)                /* glibc 2.1 */
      size = n + 1;            /* precisely what is needed */
    else                   /* glibc 2.0 */
      size *= 2;               /* twice the old size */
    p = memRealloc(p, size);
  }

  q =  strRegister(p);
  memFree(p);
  return q;
}
```

The author seems to have assumed that the standard `vsnprintf()` function returns the number of characters written, and simply returns a sentinel value if it doesn't receive enough space to format all args. This means that you can just guess a buffer size and increase it if necessary.

But on my system (Ubuntu 14.04, glibc 2.19) vnprintf causes a segmentation fault when called with too many arguments for the provided space. Did the semantics of the `snprintf()` family change that drastically in the meantime? And what is the modern way of ensuring you hand it enough buffer space?

Comment: `man vsnprintf`: *The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() do not write more than size  bytes (including  the terminating null byte ('\0')).  If the output was truncated due to this limit then  the  return  value  is  the  number  of  characters (excluding  the terminating null byte) which would have been written to the final string if enough space had been available.  Thus, a return  value  of size  or  more  means that the output was truncated.* That part of the program seems to be correct.

Comment: You are not checking for memory allocation failures.

Comment: What is `String`?  I suspect it's a `char *`, but you should provide that information, too.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You're right, fixed that.

Comment: Side issues: 1) I'd expect `size_t size` rather than `int`.  2) IMO `n >= 0` easier to follow than `n > -1`.

Comment: This loops forever if an encoding error occurs that is not due to insufficient space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the correct way to use `snprintf` and `vsnprintf` on every operating system except SunOS 4 (which has been obsolete for 20 years), so your problem is somewhere else.

I'll make a pure guess and say that I'm almost certain that your problem is that you're passing the va_list `ap` into `vsnprintf` which consumes it and then you expect it to be reset on the next call. This is incorrect and has stopped working in gcc many years ago (because it only worked on certain architectures).

Change:

```
n = vsnprintf(p, size, fmt, ap);
```

To:

```
va_list apc;
va_copy(apc, ap);
n = vsnprintf(p, size, fmt, apc);
va_end(apc);
```

And see if that helps.

Here's a simple test to see what's going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void
foo(const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
#ifdef BAD
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
#else
    va_list apc;
    va_copy(apc, ap);
    vprintf(fmt, apc);
    va_end(apc);
#endif
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
}

void
bar(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    foo(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    bar("foo %s\n", "bar");
    return 0;
}
```

When run I get this:

```
$ cc -o foo foo.c && ./foo
foo bar
foo bar
$ cc -DBAD -o foo foo.c && ./foo
foo bar
foo ����
```

Comment: You're right, this was the problem. As usual I was distracted by the fact that short strings were printed without problem but long strings crashed, so I assumed a problem with buffer overrun. I should have known that undefined behavior is never to be trusted and *will* masquerade as a different kind of problem if you give it the chance!

Answer (score 3):

Unsure on yours, but my man page on variable argument lists says:

> COMPATIBILITY
>        These macros are not compatible with the historic macros they replace.  A
>        backward compatible version can be found in the include file <varargs.h>.

As you said it is very old code, maybe the va_list received in this routine is not the va_list expected by `vsnprintf`. You should first try to extract all parameters with one header then the other to be sure (normally `vsnprintf` is stdarg.h compatible)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the code, its purpose is to detect the size needed by `sprintf` to fully write the output string in the buffer. There is a function that do this for you: `asprintf` (or `vasprintf` here).

Prototype:

```
int vasprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, va_list ap);
```

Just use it as follow:

```
String strVPrintf(const String fmt, va_list ap)
{
    char *ans;
    int n;
    n = vasprintf(&ans, fmt, ap);
    // do the checks
    return ans;
}
```

With this function, you do not need this wrapper any more, I think.

Comment: `asprintf()` and `vasprintf()` are non-standard functions.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The OP uses glibc.

Comment: The OP has not expressed a desire to write non-portable code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle OP: I'm porting some very old (> 10y) C code to modern Linuxes. (ie GNU/Linux distributions). vasprintf is a part of GNU libc implementation. So this code will work on "Linuxes". And the question is tagged with glibc.

Comment: And how does any of that lead to a recommendation to write non-portable code?