# Why does this call to sprintf_s() work, and how can I make this work on my computer?

Tags: c++, linux, function, arguments, std

I'm an inexperienced student and this was part of a posted solution to our C++ programming assignment. But it does not compile on my computer and I need help understanding why. The first error message I encountered was at sprintf_s() saying "identifier 'sprintf_s' is undeclared", which I think is because I am running linux and sprintf_s() is not a standard lib func. I have thus tried replacing it with snprintf() and the original error message disappeared (but please let me know if that was not right, my change is commented out above the original line).

After changing it, I then received the error message "argument of type 'const char *' is incompatible with parameter of type 'size_t'" and " 'float' incompatible with parameter of type 'const char *' ". I understand that the parameters for both sprintf_s() and snprintf() are 
`(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...)`
so I would think that error makes sense since size was missing from the arguments being passed. But if there must be an argument for size, then would it be correct to set it as 128? 
And why would this work without that argument on my teacher's Windows machine for sprintf_s(), but not on Linux for snprintf()? Also, he is using Visual Studio, I am using Visual Studio Code.

The entire function is shown below. If you know of another reason why I might be experiencing problems compiling what should be a working solution, please let me know!

```
bool myNode::isAccessible()
{
    return isAccessible(x, y);
}
myNode::myNode(const float location[3])
{
    x = (location[0] > 0.0) ? (int)floor(location[0] / SCALE + 0.5f) : (int)ceil(location[0] / SCALE - 0.5f);
    y = (location[1] > 0.0) ? (int)floor(location[1] / SCALE + 0.5f) : (int)ceil(location[1] / SCALE - 0.5f);
    if (isAccessible(x, y)) return;
    int originalX = x, originalY = y;
    for (int a = -1; a <= 1; a++)
        for (int b = -1; b <= 1; b++) {
            if (a == 0 && b == 0) continue;
            x = originalX + a;
            y = originalY + b;
            if (isAccessible(x, y)) return;
        }
    char buffer[128];
    //snprintf(buffer, "***AStarNode: could not find any isAccessible node for (%f, %f, %f)***", location[0], location[1], location[2]);
    sprintf_s(buffer, "***AStarNode: could not find any isAccessible node for (%f, %f, %f)***", location[0], location[1], location[2]);
    controlPanel->addMessage(buffer);
}
```

Comment: `addMessage` expects a `char*`? I would use C++ streams rather than C-io.

Comment: `sprintf_s()` is not a C++ function. It's from an optional part of of C11, that no compiler/libc vendors outside of Microsoft bothered to implement (And MS's version doesn't even fully follow the standard). It shouldn't be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly replace sprintf\_s by sprintf in C++03?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238576/how-to-properly-replace-sprintf-s-by-sprintf-in-c03)

Comment: @idclev463035818 unfortunately, this is a working solution that will only serve as the base project for me to start on my current assignment, so I'm reluctant to improve it and just need it to compile.

Comment: @Shawn So you are saying its not good practice right? I will keep that in mind. It was my teacher who decided to use sprintf_s() in their solution.

Comment: @Botje no, I am not trying to replace it with sprintf() nor vsnprintf()

Comment: Your title says "how do I get it to compile", and the answer is "by providing an implementation of `sprintf_s`, either as a function or a macro that calls snprintf."

Comment: Yeah, not good practice. MSVC will tell you to use their `_s` functions over the usual ones unless you `#define` a particular symbol. It's just them trying to lock you into their product.

Comment: no this isnt a "working solution". Even if this is code your teacher gave you should talk to him and convince him to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Error `"argument of type 'const char *' is incompatible with parameter of type 'size_t'"` and the following errors come from missing buffer size argument to `snprintf`.

The correct call to [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "***AStarNode: could not find any isAccessible node for (%f, %f, %f)***", location[0], location[1], location[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! The examples I looked at had manually set the number of bytes and was less than max buffer size, so I didn't even think about using sizeof(). Do you happen to know why my teachers solution works for him despite missing buffer size argument? Does it depend on the compilers or IDE used?

Comment: @Fatcow808 Your teacher probably used insecure `sprintf` rather than `snprintf`.