# How to determine size of va_args before vsprintf

Tags: c++

I have a function which takes variable parameters. I am not sure about the size of the parameters during compilation. Now I need to copy all those parameter to character array.

How can we determine the size of the variable parameters before usage of vsprintf? Or is it good idea to copy it to char *?

```
event(const unsigned int xyz, const char abc[], ...)
{
    //How can I determine the value of MaxLength
    char formatted_arg[MaxLength]= {'\0'};
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format_str);
        vsprint(formatted_arg,format_str,args);
    va_end(args);
    return formatted_arg;
}
```

Comment: Are you open to other methods besides this?  C++17 lets you do this in like 4 lines of code using a variadic temaplte, a `std::stringstream`, and a `std::string`.

Comment: Use `vsnprintf` to get the length needed for the buffer, create the buffer, and to the actual formatting (again using `vsnprintf`). See e.g. [this `vprintf` (and siblings) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) for how to do it. But remember that `printf` and family is not type-safe, neither is it as flexible or powerful as streams and `std::string` could be.

Comment: By the way, even if you manage to do this, returning `formatted_arg` from that function is undefined behaviour.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788305/how-do-you-call-vsnprintf-safely/

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156504/

Answer (score 1):

### Q1. How can we determine the size of the variable parameters before usage of `vsprintf`?

You can determine the number of characters which will be written by `vsprintf` by using [`vsnprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) which returns:

> The total number of characters (not including the terminating null-byte) which would have been written

Thus we could have found `MaxLength` by doing: `vsnprintf(nullptr, 0U, format_str, args)` At the risk of spelling out the obvious:

1. This requires that we are still in the `va_start` and `va_end` scope where `args` is valid
2. This is the length of `MaxLength` *not including the terminating null-byte*

### Q2. Or is it good idea to copy it to `char*`?

It is not. As [mentioned by DeiDei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221097/how-to-determine-size-of-va-args-before-vsprintf#comment99062589_56221097) returning a locally allocated array is undefined behavior. Instead consider returning a [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

I'd like to also add a couple suggestions:

1. Don't pass variables that you don't use like `xyz` and `abc` to avoid compiler warnings
2. Don't use globals like `format_str`, instead take that as a function parameter to promote function reuse

Ultimately your code should look something like:

```
string event(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list length_args;

    va_start(length_args, format);
    va_list result_args;

    va_copy(result_args, length_args);
    const auto length = vsnprintf(nullptr, 0U, format, length_args);
    string result(length, '\0');

    vsprintf(data(result), format, result_args);
    va_end(result_args);
    va_end(length_args);
    return result;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/fqyfGD)